# spilt string from text file and store the values into array instead of vectors c++

Tags: c++

I have a text file which contain the id of a person, person name , person age and today's date. I know how to read line by line and spilt the string and store it into vector and print it out.

age.txt

```
1:john:23:18-Oct-2013
2:mary:21:18-Oct-2013
3:suzy:20:18-Oct-2013
```

code

```
ifstream readFile("age.txt");
string words;
vector<string> storeWords;
while (getline(readFile, line,':'))
{
    stringstream iss(line);
    while (iss >> words) {
        storeWords.push_back(words);
    }

}

for (int i=0; i<storeWords.size(); i++) {
    cout << storeWords[i] <<endl;
}
```

output

```
1
john
23
18-Oct-2013 
2
mary
21
18-Oct-2013
3
suzy
20
18-Oct-2013
```

but I don't really have an idea how to store them into an array instead of using vector and make it 
something like

```
personId[] will contain all the id from the output;
personName[] will contain all the name from the output;
personAge[] will contain all the age from the output;
dateTime[] will contain all the date and time from the output;
```

Please advise. Thanks in advance

Comment: For that(C array) you need to have the item count in advance which you can get only by traversing the file once. And again you will traverse it for inserting which is not efficient at all. STICK to `vector`

Comment: Do you mean std::array or C array? In vector data are internally stored as array. So in C++11 `storeWords.data()` (in C++03 `&storeWords[0]`) gives you raw array.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use arrays instead of the far more flexible vectors?

Comment: Maybe something like: while (iss >> personid[i] >> personName[i] >> personage[i] >> personDate[i] ) { i++; }

Comment: @arne  let say if a user want to change only the age of john from 23 to 24 , I will prompt the user whose name he/she wants to change first and then it will search for the position of the array(e.g john's name is stored in personName[0].) and then allow him to change the age personAge[0] for john.

Comment: @user2211678 How about using maps for this kind of thing? Also, you can index vectors just the same as you can arrays, i.e. you let the user change `personAge[0]` even if `personAge` is a vector.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal alright i will give it a try

Comment: @arne thanks for advise. i will research more about maps then

Answer (score 0):

We'll need a structure to capture your data first:

```
struct Data {
   unsigned int id;
   string name;
   unsigned int age;
   time_t time; // might be a C++ data type for this
}
```

You'll essentially have a `vector<Data>`

You can overload `operator <<` to read in a string line and populate these fields. 
Most important thing is NOT to have 4 arrays for this task, but instead one array (please use vector instead) and encapsulate the fields into a bigger type.

Comment: OP already knows how to implement it through vectors. His specific question is how it can be done using arrays.

Comment: Nope - he proposed the usage of 4 arrays to accomplish this and his vector usage is of type string.